# STRING_SPLIT to Multiple Variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string that looks as such:

```
'1.25,5.34,6.9,8.6547,2.3'
```

I would like to store each comma deliminated value into variables like so but programmatically in T-SQL:

```
Declare @Var1 float
Set @Var1 = 1.25
...

@Var2 = 5.34 
@Var3 = 6.9
```

And so on so forth..

How would I do so?

Comment: Can you let us know why you need to do this?

Comment: I agree with Tim that more information on the end-goal is needed. My first thought would be to use a table variable...

Comment: I would argue that no, you don't really want to do that. This screams of being an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I'd like to insert each float variable into a separate table with specific individual column names for each value in the 5 value comma deliminated string.

Comment: You can store the result in a table parameter and use it in the INSERTs

Comment: Could you have more than 5 values, or will it always be 5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Convert to JSON**

Perhaps the easiest solution would be to convert the string to a JSON array and access the items by position :

```
declare @text varchar(200)='1.25,5.34,6.9,8.6547,2.3'
declare @json varchar(202)='[' + @text + ']'

declare @var1 numeric(18,5)= JSON_VALUE(@json,'$[0]')
declare @var2 numeric(18,5)= JSON_VALUE(@json,'$[1]')

select @var1,@var2
```

**Store in Table variable but lose the order**

A set-based solution would be to store the items in a table variable **BUT the order will probably be lost** as  Raymond Nijland noted :

```
declare @text varchar(200)='1.25,5.34,6.9,8.6547,2.3'

declare @values table (id int identity,val varchar(20))

insert into @values (val)
select trim(value) from STRING_SPLIT(@text,',') x

insert into SomeTable (value1)
select val 
from @values where ID=1
```

The only order that can be imposed is ascending or descending using ORDER BY, which assumes the input's order doesn't matter. Not very helpful.

Comment: the output rows might be in any order. The order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string. You can override the final sort order by using an ORDER BY clause on the SELECT statement (ORDER BY value).  [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: i wonder now after making mine comment how you would get a deterministic result as the function does not provide a index number it only seams to return a value?

Comment: @RaymondNijland that would be as arbitrary as leaving the order random. The OP's input isn't in ascending order

Comment: @RaymondNijland you can't really, which is why JSON is probably the best option

Comment: *"you can't really, which is why JSON is probably the best option"* indeed `ORDER BY value` can still be non deterministic (random) as the splits arn't unique.. So it's wierd reading that statement in the manual which i've made in mine first comment and there isnt a valid way in the STRING_SPLIT function to get pure 100% deterministic (fixed) result by using a index number where the split was ideally `select trim(value) from STRING_SPLIT(@text,',')  ORDER BY index_number ASC` should be possible

Comment: @RaymondNijland what's even weirder is that `STRING_SPLIT` [is considered deterministic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) even though the order isn't guaranteed. Or perhaps the order is changed consistently for different values???

Comment: very wierd indeed, not sure then if (all) Microsoft employees knows the difference between non deterministic (random) and deterministic (fixed) then.. Because those are heavy contradictions which where made in the manual

Comment: @JohnCappelletti the lack of a JSON *type* even in 2019 was a rather strong indicator that the XML strategy wasn't .... very performant.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a fixed number of variables, you can use a little XML

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = '1.25,5.34,6.9,8.6547,2.3'

Declare @Var1 float,@Var2 float,@Var3 float,@Var4 float,@Var5 float

Select @Var1 = n.value('/x[1]','float')
      ,@Var2 = n.value('/x[2]','float')
      ,@Var3 = n.value('/x[3]','float')
      ,@Var4 = n.value('/x[4]','float')
      ,@Var5 = n.value('/x[5]','float')
From  (Select cast('<x>' + replace(@S,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as n) X
```

Comment: Even easier, JSON. No need for replacements, just surround the string with square brackets